# Xslt node exists for multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0, xml-validation

I am a newbie to xslt and please forgive me if i missed any basics here.

I have an input, where i want to check whether an element/complexstrcuture exists or not. If it exists, i simply need to copy it else i need to create an empty tag. I am able to do it with the below xslt.

```
    <xsl:when test="cla:PublicID">
    <xsl:copy-of copy-namespaces="no" select="cla:PublicID"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><cla:PublicID/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

But I have around 2000 elements in the request comprising of both complex and simple elements. Hence i thought of writing a function which is not serving the purpose as well.

Is there any better way to do this using xslt templates or so?

I dont want to do the identity transform as I need to select part of request with this xslt and then popualte the elements.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of testing, you could simply create the literal result element and copy its contents. If it doesn't exist, it will be empty.

Comment: Hi michael, it can be a complex element or a simple element. how to copy its contents without copying the element name. I tried copy-of and it copies the element name again

Comment: Try `xsl:copy-of select="cla:PublicID/node()"`. Post a [mcve] if you cannot make it work.

Comment: Its populating the value if its a complex element but not copying the value if its a simple element

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: Sorry michael. Since its a very large xml, i dont wana paste it here. But below goes the sample.`<data>  
   <mainelement1>  
      <child1>value1</child1>  
      <child2>  
   <grandchild>grandchildvalue</grandchild>  
  </child2>  
   </mainelement1>  
   <mainelement2>  
      <anotherchild1>othervalue1</anotherchild1>  
      <anotherchild2>othervalue2</anotherchild2>  
   </mainelement2>  
</data>`
I need to check for child1 or child2 if its empty. child1 wont be copied if i use xsl:copy-of select="child1/node()" but the same will work for child2.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and show also your current XSLT and the expected output.